# how to use button in tabbed activity in android studio from one fragment to activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have created tabbed activity in android studio with three tabs i.e, tab 1,tab 2 and tab 3. I placed a button in tab 1. When I click the button,It will not respond. I want to go from tab 1 page to another activity called "orders" page when click the button. Please help me how to write programming?

Comment: Without code how can we help ?

Comment: show some code .

Answer (score 0):

Add an OnClickListener to your button and, on Click:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                   Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivityName.class);
                   String message = "Some extras if needed";
                   intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
                   startActivity(intent);              
                  }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **using**
this

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.panel_one_id, new MoviesFragment()).commit();
```

**replace**  `new MoviesFragment())`with your Fragment Name

Comment: Please Add more Explanation so i can help 
happy Coding :))))